# How to add a specific HTTP header to every Drupal 7 page request?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

On a Drupal 7 site, I need to send a specific HTTP header with all page responses that are returned to the browser.  I found the [documentation for drupal_add_http_header](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7.x), so I know that I need to add this code:

`drupal_add_http_header('Permissions-Policy', 'microphone=(self "https://www.example.com")');`

What I don't know is where to add the code.  Should I place it somewhere within bootstrap.inc, or is that a core file that should never be edited directly?

Also, do I need to do anything special to ensure that it only runs when Drupal is serving a web page, as opposed to being called via the Drush command line tool?

Comment: you may want to add it in a HOOK_preprocess_page function which is in a custom module or maybe in your themes .theme file. You should never change bootstrap.inc or any other drupal core file as then it will be gone if you ever upgrade. You will not have to do anything special as far as drush is concerned.

Comment: I also suggest to implement the `hook_preprocess_page`. You may prefer the `hook_init` if you want this header in every reponse regardless of whether drupal delivers an actual HTML page or not (ie. taking ajax requests into account). For the CLI concerns, you can test if `drupal_is_cli()` and react accordingly anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines with what [@EricLavault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2529954/ericlavault) said, you can also use [HOOK_page_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7.x), [HOOK_page_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7.x), or [HOOK_page_delivery_callback_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_delivery_callback_alter/7.x) even though the last two don't seem to be intended for such purposes.